# Extjs4/5: Event-delegation in Non-MVC-Applications

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs5

I can't figure out how to listen for events of child-components from the perspective of a component. The child-components are added *after* the listeners are set.

MVC-Controllers have a .control() method to listen for events regardless of the targeted components are present at the time .control() was called. As far as I understood the whole event-system (took me hours to figure out), I can use MVC or I just can't use this event-delegation (event-by-query) system. The only point where I found eventhandling as controllers utilize it is [EventDomain.listen()](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/source/EventDomain.html#Ext-app-EventDomain-method-listen). EventDomain.listen() enforces a controller as the second parameter.

I avoid MVC, because I need some sort of multiapplication (sub-application) approach with the ability to create and remove controllers as well as have multiple controllers in parallel bound to its own ui-component in different namespaces, etc.

Another approach was to call parentComponent.on(eventname, fn, scope, options) with options = { delegate: 'some child element' } as described [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?91215-jquery.live%28%29-analog-in-ExtJs&p=433836&viewfull=1#post433836). The docs say nothing on this in 5.0 as this behavior is [not in code](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/5.0.0/apidocs/source/Event4.html#Ext-util-Event) anymore.

Any ideas?

Comment: the second approach ie calling `parent.on(eventname, fn, scope, options)` should work.. are you having trouble with it? The `on` method is described in `Ext.util.Observable`..

Comment: Use ViewControllers in 5, that's what they are for.